# what does Isabelle error Cannot update finished theory "HOL.Finite_Set" mean?

Tags: import, isabelle

I am trying to use the theory `Finite_Set.thy` but when I import it

```
imports "$ISABELLE_HOME/SRC/HOL/Finite_Set"
```

the theory I am working on is not parsed. When I open the theory itself, I receive the following error:

> Cannot update finished theory "HOL.Finite_Set"

I am not sure what this means (or if it is related) or what I can do about it.

Answer (score 3):

[A similar question has already been asked on the Isabelle mailing-list](https://lists.cam.ac.uk/pipermail/cl-isabelle-users/2009-November/msg00060.html)

Finite_Set is part of HOL and cannot be edited (and you cannot click on it to open definitions and so on). You should import Main (aka `HOL.Main`) instead of only Finite_Set.

If you really want to import only Finite_Set, you should import via `HOL.Finite_Set`, not by giving a full path.

However, this should not be the cause of your problem.