# How to write expansion rules in Isabelle？

Tags: isabelle, hol

I encountered some problems while learning Isabelle's expansion rules. I hope someone can answer them, thank you.

1. I need to import Isabella's built-in HOL library to introduce some defined quantifiers. When I use Isabella2017 to open %ISABELLE_HOME%\src\HOL\HOL.thy, the seventh line "theory HOL" will report an error "Cannot update finished theory"HOL.HOL" ".
2. Have you encountered the same problem? How did you introduce the built-in rules in the HOL library?

Comment: Partial duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/60134110/12824207.

Comment: And for 2: why do you want to redefine the built-in rules? You can already use them. This is enough for nearly all applications.

Comment: Thank you, I am not redefining the built-in rules, I want to introduce the quantifiers in HOL\HOL.thy into my new file, and then use code_ to do quantifier mapping.

Comment: @W_zw I don't see why that requires redefining the quantifiers

Comment: and what is `code_to`?